# How should I rescue a baby bird, including when it's wet?

Tags: birds, bird-behaviour

A baby black bird fell in my baby's pool and I think he was there about 30 min. I took him from the pool and put him under the sun for 3-4 min to dry and then left him under the tree where there is shade. He can't fly and he doesn't do anything. Is there anything I can do for this bird? 
Temp. is 85 right now.

Comment: Problem solved! I think his parents picked him up :) He is not there anymore. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer will focus on the generalities of common American backyard [songbirds](http://www.birdsandblooms.com/birding/bird-species/songbirds/), because I haven't had experience with any other type of bird.

Rescuing a baby bird is a great thing! There are plenty of songbirds whose parents are fine if you touch their babies, which is good to know when rescuing.

You did exactly the right thing in the right order. Young birds are especially susceptible to body temperature changes, so drying in the sun and protecting in the shade was perfect!

Also, leaving it near to where you found it was very important. If it was fully formed but didn't have a lot of feathers, it was probably a nestling, who either fell out of the nest or was pushed out by another bird or predator. It's mainly helpless but a parent will usually look for it.

If it had feathers and wings, but was unable to fly, it was probably a fledgling. They're ready to leave the nest (fledge), but need to learn life skills, like eating and flying. Depending on the breed, a parent will spend up to two weeks out of the nest teaching it. That parent will go quite far to find a separated one, like yours. Sometimes what we think is an orphan or lost bird is actually under the watchful eye of a nearby parent.

At our last house we had a pool, and we found young birds in there way too often. Some say those birds aren't falling, they're going in purposely because they see their reflection in the water and think they're about to meet up with another bird!

My husband would gently scoop it out either with his hands or a pool net. We'd sit on the ground with it, get a paper towel and gently pat it down until its feathers started to fluff up. If it was tipping over, we kept it on the ground between our feet, up against a lawn chair, or in a bed of paper towels while it got its bearings. Once dry, if it still couldn't stand, we'd prop it up gently under a tree with a cutout cardboard tent. It gave shade and protection, but left room open in case it was able to fly out, or a parent came to get it. Sometimes once they were dry and got over the shock, they would fly a little bit at a time, and finally over our fence and away!

Sadly, sometimes they would pass away, and I would cry, but know we had done our best. Sometimes my husband would find one already deceased in the water and never even tell me about it because it made me too sad!

I'm really glad your bird was re-claimed by its parents! Thanks for caring!

Here are some helpful links:

[Baby Birds Out of The Nest](https://www.massaudubon.org/learn/nature-wildlife/birds/baby-birds-out-of-the-nest?)

[I found a baby bird-what do I do?](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/i-found-a-baby-bird-what-do-i-do/)

[What if you find a baby bird on the ground?](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-09-02/what-to-do-if-you-find-a-baby-bird-on-the-ground/7806518)

[Difference between Fledgling and Hatchling](https://thebirdfoodstore.com/2016/05/10/how-to-identify-a-nestling-from-a-fledgling/)

[When you should, and should not, rescue baby birds](https://www.audubon.org/news/when-you-should-and-should-not-rescue-baby-birds)

Comment: Only one problem with leaving young birds on the ground, predators like cats. If you are in an area where cats will come in the garden, you should get a spot that is safe from them. Young birds are on the menu for many species.

Comment: First when I saw him I thought he was dead already and I looked closer and saw he was struggling. He had winds and feathers but he was so small and wasn't doing anything. I left him where I found and i kept looking every 5 min to make sure he was safe. I didn't want to stay next to him because I thought his parents wouldn't come and pick him up because of me but I don't know if that was the case.

Answer (score 5):

Try calling **animal control**, the local [**Humane Society**](http://www.humanesociety.org/), or the [**SPCA**](https://www.spcai.org/). 
Depending on where you live, there may be a network of bird rehabilitation specialists who care for abandoned, sick, or injured birds with the ultimate goal of releasing them back to the wild.

When I lived in New York City I found an injured juvenile robin in a city park. I called the local animal control hotline, and they gave me the address of a website that listed about a dozen local citizens who rehabilitated birds in their homes. I brought the bird to one such specialist. Sadly, the bird was too sick to rehabilitate, but I called the same specialist about a year later and brought her a different bird, which she was able to successfully rehabilitate and release to the wild.

Comment: Well, I should have thought about calling animal control but I never thought about it. I wanted to do something before it was too late but hopefully he didn't die :) Thank you for your reply!